# 入れ子になったjson配列をjacksonのライブラリを使用してobjectに変換したい

Tags: java, json, array, jackson

下記の様なjsonをjacksonのライブラリを使用してobjectに変換したいのです。

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result":[
        {
        "hostid": "9999",
        "name": "test",
        "type": "1",
        },
        {
        "hostid": "9998",
        "name": "test2",
        "type": "1",
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

jacksonのreadValueメソッドを使用してobjectへ変換しようと試みておりますが、

```
TestDto test= mapper.readValue(json, TestDto.class);
```

下記のようなエラーとなってしまいます。

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class TestDto$Result]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
```

なお、TestDtoは下記のように宣言しております。

```
public class TestDto {

    public String jsonrpc;

    public List<Result> result;

    public class Result {
        public String hostid;

        public String name;

        public String type;
    }
    public Integer id;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Result` を [ネストされたクラス](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html)として定義するなら `static` にする必要がります。

```
public class TestDto {
    ...
    public static class Result {
        ...
    }
}
```

(なお、強いてネストされたクラスとして定義する必要はなく、 `TestDto` から独立した通常のクラスとして定義しても問題ありません。)

加えて、入力JSONも妥当ではないので修正する必要があります。

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": [
        {
        "hostid": "9999",
        "name": "test",
        "type": "1"
        },
        {
        "hostid": "9998",
        "name": "test2",
        "type": "1"
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
```

[差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/compare/b6ba2bde..db72b)